# Cannot find elements when scraping website with python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I would like to map color HSB values to English color names and Hue names. One resource I have found is **https://www.color-blindness.com/color-name-hue/**
and I am using Selenium to scrape it.
It seems though that I cannot find the elements I am interested in.
This is my attemp:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.color-blindness.com/color-name-hue/')

driver.implicitly_wait(60)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#cp1_Hue")
```

Some other attempts:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("cp1_Hue")
```

I keep getting this error message:
`NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input#cp1_Hue"} (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.82)`

Has anyone faced the same issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: solution has been written below

Comment: Try [this link](https://www.color-blindness.com/color-name-hue-tool/color-name-hue.html) to scrape whatever you wanted from the link in your post. The good news is you can use this link within requests module as the content available here are static.

Answer (score 1):

There's Iframe element, what doesn't allow to interact with elements inside it.

1. You should switch on it
2. Interact with elements what you're looking for

try this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.color-blindness.com/color-name-hue/')

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe'))

input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#cp1_Hue")
input.send_keys(10)

driver.quit()
```